# Swift, how to specify user in web socket connection to back-end SignalR hub

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a Swift iOS app that is connecting to my MVC .net core back-end app. The back-end has SignalR set up.

---

**My Hub class on server:**

```
public class ActivityHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

---

**My Startup.cs on server**

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapHub<ActivityHub>("/activityHub"); 
});
```

---

**My Connection initiation on client**

```
static var _socketConnection: URLSessionWebSocketTask?
static func connectToSocket(){
    let url = URL(string: "wss://mysite.net/activityHub")!
    _socketConnection = defaultSession.webSocketTask(with: url)
    
    _socketConnection?.resume()
}
```

When I use Vanilla web sockets on the server side without using SignalR all works fine except that there is no automatic management of connections etc, hence why I need to move to using SignalR to get the list of connections, users, etc, out of the box.

I however do not know how to specify the user property on the client, during the process of sending that socket connection request. I assume the user property that I need to specify is the some id of some sort that is guaranteed to be unique for the connect?

How do I do this?

The intent is to eventually have the server be able to send a message to a connection for a specific user, with information about specific events.

---

**UPDATE**

The connection made by SignalR [has a ConnectionID property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) and that needs to be associated and mapped to a user, which is what I'm after. The resource is from 2014 so it may be a bit stale.

Also, most importantly, I believe, [Microsoft says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0) `By default, SignalR uses the ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier from the ClaimsPrincipal associated with the connection as the user identifier`. So I might actually not have to do any mapping as I am using the Identity framework.

Comment: So it seems automatically the 'user' parameter on `Clients.All.SendAsync()` refers to ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier. 
I however cannot get the hub's `OnConnectAsync()` and `DisconnectAsync()` to be called. Anyone have any ideas on this please? Im absolutely lost on this now.

Comment: You might want to recheck your the documents you are referencing. You are mixing the ASP.NET Core SignalR which isn't compatible with clients or servers for ASP.NET SignalR. Both are still viable solutions but you need to use one or the other.

Comment: Have you tried getting per the docs for ASP.NET Core SignalR - The user identifier for a connection can be accessed by the Context.UserIdentifier property in the hub.

Comment: @FrankM which one should I be using? I am absolutely new to this space and I have no idea which one is the right one to use. I currently have installed as a nuget package the SignalR Core one.

Comment: @FrankM Yes, accessing the Context.UserIdentifier is all good at this point. I am however having issues connecting to the hub to begin with ;(
The onConnect and disconnect functions are never called. Do you see any potential issue with the way I have it set up there?

Comment: I can't say which one you should use. In the ASP.NET Core SignalR there is a feature comparison between them. I would see which best fits your needs. From there build from one of the tutorials to get an understanding of how it all works and what is required.

Comment: Right now, if you are mixing the technology then that is the issue because they do not work together. If you are not mixing the technology and only mixing the documents, then review the proper documents and as I said above, run through one of the tutorials that applies. You should get a grasp on how to start and establish the connection with that alone.

Comment: @FrankM okay I will tackle this afresh when I am not tired so I don't mix up things. It was literally 1am when I was working on this stuff.

Comment: @FrankM it turns out my current setup is correct on the server according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-mac. For the client side, I switched to using SignalRClient-Swift: https://github.com/moozzyk/SignalR-Client-Swift  to communicate with the server. The socket messaging is now working at this point.

Comment: Great to hear this is working for you now.

Comment: @FrankM you wanna add an answer so I can close this one out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to use either .NET SignalR or ASP.NET CORE SignalR for both Server and Client.

You updated to using ASP.NET CORE SignalR (server) and a SignalRClient-Swift package that works with Core.

Good to hear it is working now.